# limit of greatest integer less than

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Does $\lim_{x \to \infty} [1- \frac{1}{x}] = 0$ ? Where $[x]$ is the greatest integer less than or equal to $x$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: ^That would be valid if the greatest integer function $[ \ \cdot \ ]$ was continuous at $1$. But it isn't.

Comment: Oh ! yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.  In fact, for any $x > 1$, we have $0 < 1 - \frac{1}{x} < 1$, so$\lfloor 1 - \frac{1}{x} \rfloor = 0$.  You are taking the limit of what is, essentially, a constant function.